# Multipart upload using xlsx via karate framework is not working

Tags: karate

curl command
curl -x post "https://host_name/api/upload" -h "accept: */*" -h "createduser: myuser-email.com" -h "content-type: multipart/form-data" -f "file=@bulk-upload.xlsx;type=application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"

Karate

Background: * url 'https://host_name/api/upload'

- configure headers = { 'accept': '*/*' ,'createduser':' myuser-email.com','content-type':'multipart/form-data'}
  scenario: bulk upload of investments
  given path '/api/investments/bulkupload/upload'
  and multipart file file = {read:'@bulk-upload.xlsx',filename=bulk-upload.xlsx, contenttype: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'}
  when method post
  And status 200

When I am sending this request then I am getting a custom error from API saying that type is not xlsx.  I use the same xlsx file in swagger and it works.

I have even tried to use curl command from karate but that's not working either, I mean I don't see any response when I call curl using Karate.exec(curl(''))

Comment: multipart questions are the hardest to answer. so please refer this link, else I don't think *anyone* can help: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/1645#issuecomment-862502881